# Not able to run Jupyter notebook on Google Cloud

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run a Jupyter Notebook on Google Compute Engine(Linux VM).

After all the setting up of the VM instance, I tried to access the Jupyter Notebook on the browser with my url which is of the form:

http://INSTANCE-EXTERNAL-IP-ADDRESS:PORT-NUMBER

The browser loads for a while and then I get a connection timed out. I attempted to connect to the url with chrome and firefox.

Why do I get a connection timed out?
How do I get my notebook running?

Comment: I have the issue resolved.

Answer (score 11):

I solved the issue using this command:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser &
```

Do not forget to setup your firewall.

Comment: +1 My issue was that the firewall only allowed one port, and I wasn't using that port... fyi you can specify a range of ports.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using jupyter on Google Compute Engine without any issues. In the console, go to networking -> VPC network -> External IPs. Reserve a static IP address. Then go to VPC network -> firewall rules, create a tag allowing the protocol tcp:9999 from source IP 0.0.0.0/0. When you create your instance, associate it with both the IP address and the firewall rule.

Comment: I have it that way. I guess in in the firewall section, the target tags must have our instance name, which is the case right now.

Comment: how to associate both ip and the firewall rule to our instances

Comment: My facing same problem as above and I tried every method is given but not able to run the jupyter notebook on my google cloud system. Can anyone help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the firewall rule for the port where you want to run the jupyter (eg. 8888)
2. jupyter notebook --generate-config
   It ensures you to generate the jupyter_notebook_config.py file at location `/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`
3. sudo vi  /home/spandit/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

   `c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'`

   `c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False`

   `c.NotebookApp.port = 8888`

   Add above three lines in the config file.
4. Now run the command

   `jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8888`
5. `http://<External Static IP Address>:<Port Number>`

   e.g.

   `http://35.238.226.244:8888/`